# How can I use my existing wired home network to create a mesh-like wifi network?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ethernet

I'm considering buying a mesh wifi network for my flat, because the signal is weak in some rooms of my concrete-walled flat. Something like Google WiFi. But they're very expensive.

The thing is, I already have built-in wired ethernet cabling that goes to every room. My fibre modem/router can plug into 4 ethernet sockets in the wall of the living room, and these lead to individual sockets in other rooms, and these are all tested and working.

**So do I need a mesh system at all, or can I save money and get 'extenders' for each room, which simply plug into the ethernet sockets to connect to the main router?**

Important: I want to have the same SSID/password everywhere; my device should not need to disconnect and reconnect as I move between rooms (at least not noticeably). I want it to just 'feel' like one network that works well in every room, like it usually does in corporate offices. And all devices should be able to see each other as devices on the same network, with consistent IP addresses, even if they're connected in different rooms.

Comment: Each time you extend a wireless network you cut the bandwidth in half.  Google WiFi and other similar solutions don't necessarily have that downside.  If you are worried about speed, use LAN switches, connected to access points.  Certain premium router brands support, handing a client to the next access point automatically.  Do your research.  Your requirements indicate you should use Google WiFi

Comment: If I use Google Wifi but plug each access point into the ethernet that connects them to the base router, will that still create a single wifi network, i.e. a single SSID/password?

Comment: I am only familiar with other solutions like Google WiFi, but not specifically Google WiFi, perform the research required to determine the answer to that question.  I know my ASUS router, has the ability to communicate with other supported ASUS routers, and create a mesh of a single network.  How that network, of devices is created, is left up to the user.

Comment: I am performing the research right here ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wireless problems in large building; do I need Mesh Networking? Can I use existing Routers?](https://superuser.com/questions/1311123/wireless-problems-in-large-building-do-i-need-mesh-networking-can-i-use-existi)

Comment: Re Your "like corporates" edit - most corporates would use decent quality AP's and a structured wiring system between AP's- Ubiquity is well known in the space. Bear in mind that corporates often have additional requirements you don't - lots of devices and access policies/segmentation. This is why some APs appear complex - they need to be able to support this added stuff. You can ignore most of it in a home network, and just use basic AP functionality. At it's heart, an AP is just a WIFI to Ethernet hub/switch.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need or want a mesh network. You may want to deploy more Access Points - ie plug router into Ethernet switch, then use cabling on wall and plug in access points where coverage is weak. You should use different channels (1,6,11) if using 2.4 gig band) and the same SSID - provided you use access points and not routers you should seemlessly be able to roam through your house and the wifi will seemlessly change between access points (while keeping the same IP).

Also, the kind of equipment can make a massive difference - a good 802.11 ac or n router with multiple sntennas can easily have 3 times the range of a cheap Telco supplied the router.

Comment: Thanks, but I've looked up the access points you've described, and they're not much cheaper than something like Google Wifi. Plus they seem much more complicated if you don't know what half of these network engineering terms mean, like I don't.

Comment: @callum. Access point or AP is what most people call routers. I have covered it in many posts, so has davidgo and grawity. The terms get fuzzy because every home router is a router,switch,firewall & AP (a combo device) but almost every model of home router can be configured not only for "AP-mode" but to also support AP roaming.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart - while you are absolutely correct that routers can and often are used as AP's, I was referring to proper APs as they often do a better job (do one thing well).

Comment: @cullum An AP is not actually complicated. All you need to set up is the SSID, password and channel. Leave everything else at default. An AP will give you better performance then a mesh network because it uses half the bandwidth or less (it's not sending and receiving the same data over the limited wifi spectrum). Using a mesh network when you can use cabled backhaul is invariably picking a worse solution. What network terms are you struggling with?

Comment: Just having a bunch of access points with the same SSID isn't a real solution, there won't be any client handoff, the client would have to connect, disconnect, then connect again.  I hate to disagree but a mesh network avoids that problem.

Comment: @Ramhound - we need to agree to differ - I do this in my home and have no issues at all - even streaming (video or Skype - so low latency requirements) while moving between AP's does not faulter for me. (I'm using an outdoor ubiquity AP and  and an ASUS RT68AC router, using a cellphone as a client . Any decent wifi client should handle this process with barely a short spike in latency or less. While more sophisticated AP arrangements might do it slightly better, it's a lot better then giving up half your bandwidth and having higher latency.

Comment: Agreed, especially higher end AP's that have ASIC hardware. I posted that because of the OP's use of "cheaper". I guess I was trying to get across to him that old wrtg54's or Buffalo N-stations (really any half decent consumer grade router) can be found for a couple bucks, and would work just fine for a home network. 
Best Regards,