# WAN to LAN vs LAN to LAN routers cascading performance

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, routing

I have two routers:

- Technicolor tg789vn (old)
- Linksys EA6400 (new)

The old router works well with only one device at a time connected but becomes slow as soon as I connect multiple devices.

That's why I bought a new Linksys AC router but now my question is how can I get the best out of those routers combined?

I don't care if devices cannot share files locally the only thing I care about is having the best performance and the most simultaneous multiusers supported.

Does in cascading having the old router as the main router and the new router as the secondary router throttle the network performance?

Comment: That would depend on how you cascade and what's actually causing the problems for the older model.

Comment: I know that depends on how I cascade! that's why I am asking the question. How I should cascade to get the best multiuser performance using the two routers together knowing that the new router is better that the old one?

Comment: It depends on your options and you didn't really include anything about your physical enviornment. Maybe a WLAN bridge is the only option? Maybe you only have PowerLine or you can actually run a cable. Obviously running a cable would be the preferred option in most cases. Also it's unclear what number of users you're looking at. Having a network of 50 endpoints is different from having one with 5. This would also have an impact on what you might be able to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the new router as the main router, naturally it will have better interfaces, CPU and memory, which is what will give you the best throughput to the ISP.

Bridge the two, LAN to LAN & disable any additional features you can on the old router, as it will free up some ram, and most likely give you a little better performance.

(For the old router)
Set a static IP inside of the first routers subnet.
Firewall/Nat = disabled.
DHCP = disable.
On a non-conflicting channel (1, 6 or 11).

I wrote an explanation in another answer about this, it may be of use to you.

[Sluggish smart-home wireless devices](https://superuser.com/questions/1307203/sluggish-smart-home-wireless-devices/1307289#1307289)

Although in this situation you would probably want both routers the same SSID, as it will allow the clients to seamlessly roam between the two routers with no user intervention.

Comment: How far the two routers should be so they don't interfere? Can they be in the same room knowing that the new router has 2 channels 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz and the old router has only a 2.4Ghz channel?

Comment: Same room is fine. For the 2.4ghz radios you usually want the channels as far apart as possible. One on ch-1 & one on ch-11. I have heard you don't want the two routers within 12 inches of each other. But have never seen any performance difference in the real world

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions however I really want to thoroughly test every configuration possible. Do you recommend any tools that I can use to have a complete overview of the network performance so I can compare all setups against each others.

Comment: Sure, if the equipment supports it SNMP would be your best option. You can use jperf to test throughput on the Individual device.

Comment: Google jpef tutorials. You usually need two computers to test one device.