# Accessing devices across a LAN-WAN cascading

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, lan

Reference Image (dont consider the purple line): [image]

I bought a TL-WR940N to use as "Router 2" (R2), setted its internal LAN range to `192.168.13.x` while the "super" network "Router 1" (R1) the range is `192.168.15.x`. R2 have its WAN port connected to R1's Ethernet port, so its a LAN-WAN configuration.

I wonder if is possible to computers connected to R1 access the devices connected to R2 without needing to use another NIC, in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/936062/expanding-wireless-coverage-what-are-the-differences-between-lan-to-lan-and-lan) (marked as similar before my edits) there's this interesting excerpt:

> However, computers that are connected to the main router will not be able to communicate with the secondary router without additional configuration, and vice versa since there are two different networks.

I think i have access to some routing configuration on R2 (again, a TP-Link's TL-WR940N), and my question is if is really possible to make connections across those two networks, if yes what i need to config on both routers.

Thanks in advance for any helps!

Comment: Do you need the subnets separate? Or can they be on the same continuous IP address space? Either one has been asked many times here. You probably want to bridge the two routers. If not you will have to stumble through troubleshooting static routes & NAT issues on both routers. Btw the search terms are "bridging & cascading"

Comment: Interesting Tim. In fact i was asking here and on reddit about how to ease traffic in my LAN because i had issues with my internet due to this (i use a wifi ip cam) and some folks told me to separate the networks. I dont know if subnets ranges should be different to isolate traffic; btw i will search the terms you told me

Comment: This post may be of use to you, it's not the subnet separation that counts, But collision domain & co-channel interference when dealing with wireless devices. https://superuser.com/questions/1307203/sluggish-smart-home-wireless-devices/1307289#1307289

Comment: I think i found an [interesting guide](https://www.linksys.com/th/support-article?articleNum=132275) about cascading. Sadly its from Linksys and is focused on their routers control panels, but i think i can adapt this for my tp-link router.. Currently the closest setup i have is LAN-WAN, and to access seamlessy i need to use LAN-LAN

Comment: The issue really isn't manufacturer-specific at all (and "will not be able to communicate" in that article is a total lie). But I'm sure there have been _many_ threads here in SU about this? (Short summary: "Add a static route on router 1")

Comment: @vico, did you get this figured out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expanding wireless coverage: What are the differences between LAN to LAN and LAN to WAN when it comes to connecting two wireless routers?](https://superuser.com/questions/936062/expanding-wireless-coverage-what-are-the-differences-between-lan-to-lan-and-lan)

Comment: Yes Tim, and in your last linked question the answers indicates its possible to make a router 1-bound device to connect to a router 2-bound device using router 2 routing config. I think i have this options avaiable on my R2 so i just need to figure out how to do this. Perharps time for another question or editing this one. Thanks!

Comment: Edited my question. I hope more light are shed. Thanks for all!

Comment: @vico set router1 (R1) LAN address to 192.168.1.1, set the DHCP range on R1 to 192.168.1.2 ~ 192.168.1.254. set the LAN address of R2 to 192.168.1.254, disable DHCP on R2, and disable the NAT/Firewall if you have the option to. connect the two LAN-port <---> LAN-port. set the SSID & WPA2-PSK on R2 to exactly match the SSID & WPA2-PSK of R1. (The SSID is case-sensitive). make sure that the two are on non-conflicting channels. 1, 6, or 11 are the non-overlapping channels for the 2.4ghz band. you should be able to now communicate in either direction from either router. added bonus AP-roaming!