# Is there a way to assign wifi clients to wireless routers without using extra hardware

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have 2 wireless routers. I want to share the wifi load between them. Is there a way to assign clients to a single router without using extra hardware?

I can't figure out a solution mostly because the clients have the power to choose where to connect on their own (either automatically or manually)

The routers that I am using are

- Linksys WAG200G
- INTRACOM NETFASTER IAD 2 PSTN

Comment: Telling us what type of router(s) you're using would go a long way. Since if there is a possible answer it would be in the router's config.

Comment: updated question

Comment: I don't really understand your issue here. Is this a house or an office or a business? Are the "clients" fixed or are they going to change on a daily basis? If for example you have 50 fixed clients, how do you know that if you place 25 on 1 router and 25 on another router, you're going to somehow balance the network load?

Comment: It's a house with about 7 wifi clients. Indeed my goal is to balance the load (half clients to one router and half clients to the other router)

Comment: Are the routers placed on opposites sides of the house? or are they next to each other?

Comment: They are in different rooms, the rooms are next to each other

Comment: This answer might help you out, https://superuser.com/questions/1307203/sluggish-smart-home-wireless-devices, it sounds like bridging them and using Mac filters may be the better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Method**

Limit the first Router to 3 clients.
Meaning in your router config only allows 3 available spots in your router pool. 
So for example 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.4

Then on the second Router, you could allow 50 for the rest of the clients and anyone that visits your location.

**Second method**

Give 3 of your clients, the password to one router
Give the other 4 clients password to the another router.

**Third method**

If your router(s) allows this, you can assign static LAN IP address to clients. 
Assign each person's mac address a specific IP address. This will give you full control over heavy bandwidth users and light bandwidth users.

Then reject specific IPs from accessing either of the routers. And split up the load as you see fit.

**Forth method**

(I know you said you didn't want to purchase any hardware)

But I would recommending buying a stand alone Access Point that only broadcasts a Wifi signal. Make sure the AP exceeds your ISP's bandwidth limitations so you are assured that the issue isn't with your internet connect but the reliability with your access point's speed.